Triangulation of N datapoints in $\mathbb{R}^d$
Given a set of $N$ data points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, is a triangulation always composed of the same number of "triangles", i.e. $d$-simplices?
This seems to be the case when $d=2$. The number of triangles in this case is $2N - h - 2$, where $h$ is the number of points from the boundary of the convex hull.
But what about any dimension $d$?
I read in many texts that the number of simplices is $O(N^{\lceil d/2\rceil})$, but I am looking for a more specific formula, similar to the $d=2$ case.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Does the word "data" have meaning here, or are you asking just about a set of $N$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

What does "triangulation" mean? If I have 6 points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I can form a simplicial complex composed of two disjoint triangles. That doesn't seem to agree with your formula, so presumably it's not what you mean by triangulation.

You can forget the word "data". I mean $N$ points in general position.
We can call $S$ the set of $N$ points.
What I mean by "triangulation" is a partition of the convex hull of $S$ into a set of d-simplices, meaning that the union of the d-simplices is the convex hull, and that the intersection of any pair of d-simplices has an empty interior.

This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.
If there is going to be a formula, it will have to be more complicated than just counting the vertices in the convex hull. Imagine two regular tetrahedra glued along their base, one pointing up and another pointing down: we have $5$ vertices — three for the base, one for the top point, one for the bottom point — whose convex hull is divided into two $3$-simplices. Note that if we project vertically to the triangle in the center, the top and bottom vertices land in the interior of the triangle.
Now take the top and bottom point and move them so that their projections still coincide but land outside the triangle. The convex hull will have the same number of vertices, maybe even the same number of edges, but will now consist of, I believe, three $3$-simplices.
Edit: in contrast, consider this case in $\mathbb{R}^2$: if you have two equilateral triangles glued along their base, then you have four vertices, all on the exterior of the convex hull and two triangles, and the formula holds. If you slide the top and bottom vertices to the side, then eventually you have to add a new edge in the convex hull, and also a new triangle, but one of the vertices disappears into the interior, so the formula continues to hold. In the $3$-dimensional case, the vertices all remain on the exterior, and while one edge disappears into the interior, a new one is created on the exterior, so the vertex and edge count in the convex hull remain the same.

A picture: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=sgdzxj

Interesting example! Although I agree that, if you change the position of the points, the number of d-simplices of the triangulation will be different. Similarly, for $d=2$, if we change the position of the points, less or more points will be at the boundary of the convex hull, and it will change the number of triangles.
My question is about a specific set of points with specific positions. Various triangulations may exist. Will all triangulations have the same number of d-simplices?

One of the points of this example is that it makes it seem unlikely, to me at least, that there will be a nice formula involving the number vertices and edges in the convex hull. See also my edit about a similar $d=2$ case.

Ok, a nice formulation might be out of reach, but is it at least possible to prove that whatever this number of d-simplices is, for a specific set of points in a specific position, any triangulation will have the same number of d-simplices?
